# Insert query speed up while using index

Tags: mysql, sql-server, indexing

I know index increase the select query but slows down the insert query because every time the data is inserted the indexes are also updated.

I need to use all the queries insert/update/delete/select in my useraccount table.

Now I want to know Should I use index .If yes,then please tell me some ways to speed up insert query while using index

Comment: Why did you tag this with MySQL **and** SQL Server?

Comment: I think at least somebody will take a look at this question's tags

Comment: Do not worry, I think there are a lot of people here who are hunting for any question to answer and thus to earn reputation points. For example, here I am. I am grateful for every up votes and accepted answers. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use index every time where the benefits of faster queries are convincingly greater than the disadvantages of slower inserts, updates and deletes. Use queries on columns that are frequently used in WHERE conditions.
If you have mass inserts, you might want to drop/disable/unuse the index(es) and rebuild them after the action.

Comment: Suppose my one user has dropped index while insertion and at the mean time another user is selecting data from db,then may i know what is the need of index

Comment: Note that indexes can (and very often do) speed up `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements.

Comment: Indeed, indexes can/do accelerate updates and deletes, so I only mentioned inserts when the indexes can be dropped/disabled/unused. But dropping/disabling/unusing the index is typically done in data warehouses during the ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) process. During this process users typically do not use the database. In OLTP systems indexes typically not manipulated, so they are always available and thus the cost of index maintenance on the fly cannot be avoided.